# Determinant of matrix using only trace

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

How to show that the determinant of matrix $X$ can be calculated using only traces of powers of $X$? For example for $3 \times 3$ matrix $X$ true that
$$
\text{det}A = \dfrac{1}{6}((\text{tr} A)^3 - 3 \text{tr}A \;\text{tr}A^2 + 2 \text{tr}A^3)
$$
Where i can read about this? I think it's very common result but still i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: It should be possible to get formulas like this using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)

Comment: These formulas can also be seen as a result of using the [Faddeev-LeVerrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm)

Comment: There is also [this expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties) in terms of the traces of the powers of $A$ that you might find interesting:
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left(\textstyle\bigwedge^k A\right) = \frac{1}{k!}  
\begin{vmatrix}  \operatorname{tr}A  &   k-1 &0&\cdots & \\
\operatorname{tr}A^2  &\operatorname{tr}A&  k-2 &\cdots & \\
 \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots    \\
\operatorname{tr}A^{k-1} &\operatorname{tr}A^{k-2}& & \cdots & 1    \\ 
\operatorname{tr}A^k  &\operatorname{tr}A^{k-1}& & \cdots & \operatorname{tr}A
\end{vmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Setting $k$ equal to the size of $A$ in the above gives a formula for the determinant of $A$.